# what will be the jQuery where i can display the text value of selected checkbox , dropdown list and flipswitch in the popup

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jquery-mobile, popup

This is the html for the form to take input and on clicking submit all the input will be displays in the popup window. Currently i am able to only display text in the popup. Not able to show text of selected checkbox and dropdown list. Only number for dropdown and ON for checkbox if its selected or not.

```
   <body>
      <div data-role = "page1">
         <div data-role = "header">
            <h2>Registration Form</h2>
         </div>

         <div data-role = "main" class = "ui-content">
            <form >
               <label for = "fname">Name</label>
                  <input type = "text" name = "fname" id = "fname" 
                     placeholder = "Full Name">


                 <label for="textarea">Address:</label>
                 <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>



               <label for = "select">Gender:</label>
               <select name = "select" id = "select">
                  <option value = "0">Select</option>
                  <option value = "1">Male</option>
                  <option value = "2">Female</option>
                  <option value = "3">Other</option>
                </select>


               <label for = "select1">Category:</label>
               <select name = "select1" id = "select1">
                  <option value = "0">Select</option>
                  <option value = "1">Open</option>
                  <option value = "2">OBC</option>
                  <option value = "3">SC/ST</option>
                  <option value = "4">Other</option>
               </select>

               <label for = "select2">State:</label>
               <select name = "select2" id = "select2">
                 <option value = "0">Select</option>
                 <option value = "1">Pune</option>
                 <option value = "2">Chennai</option>
                 <option value = "3">Bangalore</option>
                </select>

               <label for = "select3">District:</label>
               <select name = "select3" id = "select3">
                  <option value = "0">Select</option>
                  <option value = "1">A</option>
                  <option value = "1">A</option>
                  <option value = "1">A</option>
                  <option value = "2">B</option>
                  <option value = "2">B</option>
                  <option value = "2">B</option>
                  <option value = "3">C</option>
                  <option value = "3">C</option>
                  <option value = "3">C</option>
               </select>



               Education Qualification
               <label for = "checkbox1">
                  <input type = "checkbox" id = "checkbox1">BE
               </label>

               <label for = "checkbox2">
                  <input type = "checkbox" id = "checkbox2">MCA
               </label>

                 Newsletter
               <input type = "checkbox" data-role = "flipswitch"><br/>


            </form>

                <a href = "#popup_dialog" data-rel = "popup" data-position-to = "window" 
               data-transition = "pop" class = "ui-btn ui-btn-b" onclick="showMessage()">Submit</a>
          </div>
         </div>


    <div data-role = "popup" id = "popup_dialog" data-theme = "b" 
               data-dismissible = "false">

               <div data-role = "header" >
                  <h2 class = "ui-title">Confirmation</h2>
               </div>

               <div data-role = "main" >


              <p> Name: <span id = "display_fname"></span> </p>

              <p> Address: <span id = "display_textarea"></span> </p>

              <p> Gender: <span id = "display_select"></span> </p>

              <p> Category: <span id = "display_select1"></span> </p>

              <p> State: <span id = "display_select2"></span> </p>

              <p> District: <span id = "display_select3"></span> </p>

              <p> Qualification: <span id = "display_checkbox"></span> </p>


               </div>


            <div data-role = "footer" >

                  <a href = "#" class = "ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b btn-1" data-rel = "back">
                     OK</a>
                  <a href = "#" class = "ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b btn-2" data-rel = "back">
                     Back</a>
               </div>
       </div> 
   </body>
```

This is the jQuery i have used for displaying the form input on the popup.
Also tell me if there is better way to write the entire jQuery.

```
< script >
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#select2").change(function() {
      if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
        $(this).data('options', $('#select3 option').clone());
      }
      var id = $(this).val();
      var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
      $('#select3').html(options);
    });
  });


function showMessage() {
  var name = $("#fname").val();
  var address = $("#textarea").val();
  var gender = $("#select").val();
  var category = $("#select1 option:selected").html();
  var state = $("#select2").val();
  var district = $("#select3").val();
  var qualification = $("#checkbox1").val();


  $("#display_fname").html(name);
  $("#display_textarea").html(address);
  $("#display_select").html(gender);
  $("#display_select1").html(category);
  $("#display_select2").html(state);
  $("#display_select3").html(district);
  $("#display_checkbox").html(qualification);

}
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you calling the function showMessage() ?

Comment: In the button just after form. Every thing is working fine just improve "var qualification = $("#checkbox1").val();" this code so that i can display the inner text.

Comment: Check my answer below. Edited your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Checkboxradio widget:**

jQuery Mobile is enhancing the `input` by wrapping it in a `div` with a more pleasant custom `ui-checkbox` class.

As You are already using the `label for` attribute, I suggest You to unwrap the `input` from the `label` and put the `label` side by side with the `input`. This way, You can easily get the caption of the `Checkboxradio widget` by searching the corresponding `label` inside that parent `div`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    var qualifications = [];
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(index) {
      if (this.checked) {
        var caption = $(this).parent().find("label").text();
        qualifications.push(caption);
      }
    });
    $("#qualifications span").text(qualifications.toString());
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page-one" data-role="page">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="page-1-content">
      <label for="checkbox1">BE</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
      <label for="checkbox2">MCA</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
    </div>
    <pre id="qualifications">Qualifications:<span></span></pre>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Flipswitch widget:**

as the `Flipswitch widget` can be of type `select` or type `checkbox`,  there is already a built-in method in the framework to get the text of the caption, documented here:
[jQuery Mobile Flipswitch Widget](http://api.jquerymobile.com/flipswitch/#option-onText)

**Selectmenu widget:**

I believe there shouldn't be any problem, as the options can have any text value You want, just filter out and grab the selected options. 
Anyway, here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#select-custom-19").change(function() {
    var options = [];
    $("#select-custom-19 option").filter(":selected").each(function(index) {
        var option = $(this).text();
        options.push(option);
    });
    $("#options span").text(options.toString());
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page-one" data-role="page">
    <div class="ui-field-contain">
      <label for="select-custom-19">Multiple:</label>
      <select name="select-custom-19" id="select-custom-19" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
        <option>Choose options</option>
        <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
        <option value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
        <option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
        <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <pre id="options">Options:<span></span></pre>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code.

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#select2").change(function() {
      if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
        $(this).data('options', $('#select3 option').clone());
      }
      var id = $(this).val();
      var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
      $('#select3').html(options);
    });
  });


    function showMessage() {

      var name = $("#fname").val();
      var address = $("#textarea").val();
      var gender = $("#select").val();
      var category = $("#select1 option:selected").html();
      var state = $("#select2").val();
      var district = $("#select3").val();
      var qualification = $(".education_radio").val();
      var newsletter = "Off";

      if($("#newsletter").prop("checked")){
        newsletter = "On";
      }


      $("#display_fname").html(name);
      $("#display_textarea").html(address);
      $("#display_select").html(gender);
      $("#display_select1").html(category);
      $("#display_select2").html(state);
      $("#display_select3").html(district);
      $("#display_checkbox").html(qualification);
      $("#display_newsletter").html(newsletter);
    }
```

### HTML

```
<div data-role = "page1">
         <div data-role = "header">
            <h2>Registration Form</h2>
         </div>

         <div data-role = "main" class = "ui-content">
            <form >
               <label for = "fname">Name</label>
                  <input type = "text" name = "fname" id = "fname" 
                     placeholder = "Full Name">


                 <label for="textarea">Address:</label>
                 <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>



               <label for = "select">Gender:</label>
               <select name = "select" id = "select">
                  <option value = "0">Select</option>
                  <option value = "1">Male</option>
                  <option value = "2">Female</option>
                  <option value = "3">Other</option>
                </select>


               <label for = "select1">Category:</label>
               <select name = "select1" id = "select1">
                  <option value = "0">Select</option>
                  <option value = "1">Open</option>
                  <option value = "2">OBC</option>
                  <option value = "3">SC/ST</option>
                  <option value = "4">Other</option>
               </select>

               <label for = "select2">State:</label>
               <select name = "select2" id = "select2">
                 <option value = "0">Select</option>
                 <option value = "1">Pune</option>
                 <option value = "2">Chennai</option>
                 <option value = "3">Bangalore</option>
                </select>

               <label for = "select3">District:</label>
               <select name = "select3" id = "select3">
                  <option value = "0">Select</option>
                  <option value = "1">A</option>
                  <option value = "1">A</option>
                  <option value = "1">A</option>
                  <option value = "2">B</option>
                  <option value = "2">B</option>
                  <option value = "2">B</option>
                  <option value = "3">C</option>
                  <option value = "3">C</option>
                  <option value = "3">C</option>
               </select>



               Education Qualification
               <label for = "radio1">
                  <input type = "radio" id = "radio1" value="BE" class="education_radio" name="education">BE
               </label>

               <label for = "radio2" value="MCA">
                  <input type = "radio" class="education_radio" id = "radio2" name="education">MCA
               </label>

                 Newsletter
               <input type = "checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" id="newsletter" name="flip-1"><br/>


            </form>

                <a href = "#popup_dialog" data-rel = "popup" data-position-to = "window" 
               data-transition = "pop" class = "ui-btn ui-btn-b" onclick="showMessage()">Submit</a>
          </div>
         </div>


    <div data-role = "popup" id = "popup_dialog" data-theme = "b" 
               data-dismissible = "false">

               <div data-role = "header" >
                  <h2 class = "ui-title">Confirmation</h2>
               </div>

               <div data-role = "main" >


              <p> Name: <span id = "display_fname"></span> </p>

              <p> Address: <span id = "display_textarea"></span> </p>

              <p> Gender: <span id = "display_select"></span> </p>

              <p> Category: <span id = "display_select1"></span> </p>

              <p> State: <span id = "display_select2"></span> </p>

              <p> District: <span id = "display_select3"></span> </p>

              <p> Qualification: <span id = "display_checkbox"></span> </p>

                   <p> Newsletter: <span id = "display_newsletter"></span> </p>

               </div>


            <div data-role = "footer" >

                  <a href = "#" class = "ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b btn-1" data-rel = "back">
                     OK</a>
                  <a href = "#" class = "ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b btn-2" data-rel = "back">
                     Back</a>
               </div>
       </div>
```

You need to give value to your checkboxes. I have converted them into radio as education can only be one. Also made changes in newsletter checkbox please review it.

Here is a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/smitraval27/pen/GxEyzR).